# Stacked Autoencoder for Classification

Tags: tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I have trained a stacked autoencoder which only contains the encoder part and has attached a classifier at the end. The model looks like below:

```
input_ = layers.Input(shape=(78,))
encoder = layers.Dense(50,activation='relu')(input_)
encoder_one = layers.Dense(30,activation='relu')(encoder)
encoder_two = layers.Dense(15,activation='relu')(encoder_one)
classifier = layers.Dense(11,activation='softmax')(encoder_two)
autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=classifier)
```

In order to check if the model is working fine I cannot predict classes for this like which I can do for other models like CNN or RNN. How do I achieve that? I used stacked autoencoder with the last layer as classifier long ago in tensorflow 1.6. Previously I used to do

```
y_pred = autoencoder.predict(X_test).ravel()
```

But this above code does not seem to work for Tensorflow 2.3 anymore.

Comment: You need to clarify "does not seem to work", what happens?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy If you see my asnwer below the ravel() function used to do the same thing which is why I didn't have to worry about finding the threshold and converting the predicted probabilities to its desired classes. The ravel() function I believe does not exist. I may be wrong.

Comment: What you said made no sense to me, you still need to describe the problem properly, else the question is not useful for other people. ravel does exist in numpy.

Answer (score 0):

The way to predict classes using the classifier layer in and encoder is the following:

```
predicted_classes = autoencoder.predict(X_test)
predicted_classes = np.argmax(np.round(predicted_classes),axis=1)
```